# how to pass parameter to oracle update statement from csv file and excluding null values from csv

Tags: oracle, shell, csv

I have a situation where I have following csv file(say file.csv) with following data:

```
AcctId,Name,OpenBal,closingbal
1,abc,1000,
2,,0,
3,xyz,,
4,,,
```

how can I loop through this file using unix shell and say for example for column $2 (Name) , I want to get all occurances of Name column accept null values and pass it to for example following oracle query with single quotes '','' format?

```
select * from account 
where name in (collection of values from csv file column name 
               but excluding null values) 
and openbal in 
and same thing for column 3 (collection of values from csv file column Openbal 
                          but  excluding null values)
    and same thing for column 4 (collection of values from csv file column 
                              closingbal but excluding null values)
```

In short what I want is pass the csv column values as input parameter to oracle sql query and update query too ? but again I dont want to include null values in it. If a column is entirely null for all rows I want to exclude it too?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you'd want to loop through this file in a unix shell script: perhaps because you can't think of any better approach?  Anyway, I'm going to skip that and offer a pure Oracle solution.

We can expose data in CSV files to the database using external tables.  These are like regular tables except their data comes from files in OS directories on the database server (rather than the database's storage).   [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/schema.htm#CNCPT1141).

Given this approach it is easy to write the query you want.  I suggest using sub-query factoring to select from the external table once.

```
with cte as ( select name, openbal, closingbal
              from your_external_tab )
select * 
from account a
where a.name in ( select cte.name from cte )
and a.openbal in ( select cte.openbal from cte )
and a.closingbal in ( select cte.closingbal from cte )
```

The behaviour of the IN clause is to exclude NULL from consideration.

Incidentally, that will return a different (larger) result set from this:

```
select a.* 
from account a
     , your_external_table e
where a.name = e.name 
and a.openbal= e.openbal 
and a.closingbal = e.closingbal
```

Comment: The reason for taking CSV file as input is to design a solution for users, as users are restricted to run queries themselves. We are asking users to put their specified parameter in a csv file and we automate the oracle script to pickup parameter from their inputted CSV file. Its user friendly for users to put input data in CSV file thats why we are using this approach.